# OS X 10.11 beta 6 and Xcode problems

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, beta

Just installed OS X 10.11 beta 6, apparently it has a problem with latest version of Xcode (7 beta 4). Unable to run the simulator, constantly crashing.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform 
cd Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib
```

(or wherever your Xcode 7 beta 4 is located)

```
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

found on: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/warning-10-11-beta-6-is-unusable-with-either-xcode-6-or-7-right-now.1905465/

Comment: Thank you! This solution fix all strange issues for me.
Like don't compiling xibs and infinity indexing.